# add grid to plt.subplots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, subplot

I want to add grid to subplots of plt like:
[image]

and this is my code(`data` is a dict of (string, padas DataFrame)):

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)
for row in ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)):
    for axes in row:
        data['DPTP'].plot(ax=axes, x="time", y="fitness",
                          label="DPTP(r = 30)", linestyle='dashed', grid=True)

for i in range(2):
    lb = "Preset {}".format(i)
    data[str(i)].plot(ax=ax2, x="time", y="fitness", label=lb, grid=True)
ax1.set_title("a")
ax1.grid(True)

for i in range(2, 4):
    lb = "Preset {}".format(i)
    data[str(i)].plot(ax=ax3, x="time", y="fitness", label=lb, grid=True)
ax2.set_title("b")
ax2.grid(True)

for i in range(4, 6):
    lb = "Preset {}".format(i)
    data[str(i)].plot(ax=ax4, x="time", y="fitness", label=lb, grid=True)
ax3.set_title("c")
ax3.grid(True)

for i in range(6, 10):
    lb = "Preset {}".format(i)
    data[str(i)].plot(ax=ax4, x="time", y="fitness", label=lb, grid=True)
ax4.set_title("d")
ax4.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

in the each for-loop I have `grid=True` and I think I can set each subplot to have grid, but my plot only has grid on the first subplot:
[image: ![enter image description here]
And even `ax.set_title()` does not work for subplots.
Why?

Comment: Try putting the `ax.grid()` command after the dataframe `plot` command. That worked for me.

Comment: @K.Cl No that does not work for me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) takes a `grid` boolean argument, set it to `True`.

Comment: @paime I added grid=True in all 5 for-loops, but does not work either.

Comment: Also, note that your creation of subplots is wrong. You should get a 2x2 array of axes, not a 1x4. You have to flatten the array to assing the axes like you did. Maybe you have some residual data from the session so nothing is complaining. I would also restart the kernel.

Comment: Yes @K.Cl is right, `fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(2, 2)` should raise a `ValueError`, `fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)` is what you should do.

Comment: @paime I have tried your suggestion but it does not work. I re-editted the post and there is my newest result from the code in it.

Comment: @kaiyuwei You didn't have to change the for loop line .. Btw we don't have any data to reproduce so we can't really help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're somewhat new so I'll be kind and provide a solution but you should have provided the mock data to work on, **that's your job when asking a question here**.

So here is the part you should have provided, construction of data:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Mock data
time = np.linspace(0.3, 2, 600)
fitness = lambda i: 1 / (time + 0.05 * (i + 1)) - 0.1 * (i + 1)
dataframe = lambda i: pd.DataFrame({"time": time, "fitness": fitness(i)})

data = {"DPTP": dataframe(0)} | {str(i): dataframe(i + 1) for i in range(10)}
```

Now let's create the axes, I just refactored a bit using dicts so plotting part is shorter and independant:

```py
# Prepare axes and axes metadata
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)

ax_titles = {ax1: "a", ax2: "b", ax3: "c", ax4: "c"}
key_to_ax = (
    dict.fromkeys(["0", "1"], ax1)
    | dict.fromkeys(["2", "3"], ax2)
    | dict.fromkeys(["4", "5"], ax3)
    | dict.fromkeys(["6", "7", "8", "9"], ax4)
)
```

And finally the plotting part.
Here you have two choices, either:

- set `grid=True` as argument to all the `df.plot` calls
- use `ax.grid()` **once you're done plotting new lines on that `ax`.**

```
# Plot
for ax in (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4):
    data["DPTP"].plot(
        ax=ax, x="time", y="fitness", label="DPTP(r = 30)", linestyle="dashed"
    )

for i in range(10):
    data[str(i)].plot(ax=key_to_ax[str(i)], x="time", y="fitness", label=f"Preset {i}")

for ax in (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4):
    ax.set_title(ax_titles[ax])
    ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

[image: subplots with grids]

Comment: Thank you for you patience and kind suggestion. It works for me!